# Get file from Process.Start()-Method

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I'm trying to retrieve a file from the `Process.Start()`-Method.

Following scenario is given:

I obtain a link from a third party program. This link can be a UNC-path, direct link to PDF/JPG/TIF-files, such as "www.certainServer.de/test.pdf", as well as link to programs on the server, which return a special file type, such as "www.certainServer.de/test.aspx".

I open the file like this

```
Process.Start(_path)
```

If the link is like "www.certainServer.de/test.aspx" the returned file is automatically downloaded to the deposited download folder.

Is there a opportunity to retrieve the downloaded file or the path to the downloaded file?

The returned `Process`-object from the `Process.Start()`-Method doesn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. But there ist no more code I can provide. It's just this one line togehther with a link I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process.Start` does not necessarily download a file. It simply *starts a process*.  You just as easily could start Notepad, which has no side effects (except, of course, what you *do* with notepad once it's started). If the process you start (in your case, calling a web page) has external effects, the process engine knows nothing about it.

It sounds like you *know* where the file is supposed to be deposited, so you could use something like a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to be alerted when a new file is added (which doesn't necessarily mean it came from your process, though) or get a list of files before and after the process is run.

But there's nothing inherent to `System.Process` to definitively know what that process *did*.

Another option might be to call the URL from your code (using `WebClient` or something similar) and capturing the result (which might be a file, or just a web page, depending on the URL). It's not as general as starting a process and letting the default browser handle the download, but it would capture the results more definitively.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.